# Bibliography: \citeauthor without natbib?

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing an article for the ECAI conference, which requires the use of a custom LaTeX bibliography style called "ecai". Unfortunately, it seems that this style does not support the \citeauthor command, which I would like to use to automatically write the author name instead of hard-coding it every time.

Do you know of any way to use \citeauthor without importing natbib or changing the bibliography style?

here is the source code of the template:
https://vtex-soft.github.io/texsupport.iospress-ecai/
additional source
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ecai-2023-template/rdjprqmzgffr

Comment: A command like `\citeauthor` needs support from the bibliography style. If the style does not support it, it is pretty tricky to add. In any case a machinery like that of `natbib` would have to be used or re-implemented.

Comment: Is the `ecai` bibliography style available online? If so, where?

Comment: yes here
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ecai-2023-template/rdjprqmzgffr
or 
https://vtex-soft.github.io/texsupport.iospress-ecai/

Comment: The `.bst` file available at https://github.com/vtex-soft/texsupport.iospress-ecai/blob/master/ecai.bst (linked from https://vtex-soft.github.io/texsupport.iospress-ecai/) does not expose the author name in a usable format to TeX. It would have to be modified in order provide the necessary data. And then one would have to implement something akin to `natbib`'s feature on the TeX-side of things. Not technically impossible, but probably not something the editors of the ECAI proceedings are keen on. ...

Comment: ... I'd say that in this case the disappointing answer is that you have to write the author names manually yourself. (The lack of support for a `\citeauthor` feature might suggest that the conference publishers don't expect something like this to be used very often, so maybe you'll be OK if you try not to mention people's name that often.)

Comment: It's of course a matter of style, but personally I'm not against using numeric references as noun phrases, for example instead of "Smith et al. note that their method works only for English" you can write "[25] note that their method works only for English". Alternatively you can rephrase as a less conversational "Some methods work only for English [25]".